# How to define source fields in Scalding

Tags: scala, hadoop, cascading, scalding

I was working in Cascading a month back. Now we are trying to implement the same in Scalding. I have one basic question.

How can i define my source & sink schema in Scalding ??

Below is the procedure that we followed in Cascading

```
    SrcFields sourcefields = new SrcFields();
    SinkFields sinkfields = new SinkFields();
    Fields source = sourcefields.sourceFields();
    Fields sink = sinkfields.sinkfields();
    Scheme sourceScheme = new TextDelimited(source,",");
    Scheme sinkScheme = new TextDelimited(sink,",");
```

Answer (score 0):

In Scalding, you can use either [Fields based](https://github.com/twitter/scalding/wiki/Fields-based-API-Reference) or [Typed](https://github.com/twitter/scalding/wiki/Type-safe-api-reference) interface, as per [Source documentation](https://github.com/twitter/scalding/wiki/Scalding-Sources). In former, you would use [Csv](http://twitter.github.io/scalding/index.html#com.twitter.scalding.Csv) or [Tsv](http://twitter.github.io/scalding/index.html#com.twitter.scalding.Tsv) classes to read or write.

For typed interface, you would use [TypedCsv](http://twitter.github.io/scalding/index.html#com.twitter.scalding.TypedCsv$) or [TypedTsv](http://twitter.github.io/scalding/index.html#com.twitter.scalding.TypedTsv$) classes.

You can find examples in Scalding Tutorial: https://github.com/twitter/scalding/blob/develop/tutorial/Tutorial6.scala , https://github.com/twitter/scalding/blob/develop/tutorial/TypedTutorial.scala